# GurobiPersistent vs APPSI

Tags: pyomo, gurobi

Pyomo offers various interfaces to Gurobi. Recently the GurobiDirect and (subclass) GurobiPersistent classes have been improved, allowing the customization of the underlying Gurobi environment.

With these recent updates, what are the advantages of using the APPSI (Auto-Persistent Pyomo Solver Interfaces) interface to Gurobi over using GurobiPersistent if both offer persisting the Gurobi model between consecutive runs and customizing the Gurobi environment?